# Oozie Spark Action (Containing HiveContext) Giving java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, out-of-memory, oozie, hivecontext

I'm trying to run a spark-scala Self-Contained App in Oozie.
Please note that I'm using CDH5.13 Quickstart VM with 20G of RAM (containing Cloudera Manager, HUE ..., and I uppgraded Java from 7 to 8).

**The code does pretty much nothing, it just create HiveContext and then create a  Hive table:**

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object ThirdApp {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Third Application")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.src (key INT, value STRING)")
}
}
```

**sbt file:**

```
name := "Third Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0",
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive"  % "1.6.0")
```

The App worked fine when I submited it (in shell), and the Hive table was created.
But when I runned the same App in oozie it gives Memory issues.

**Please note that i'm used to run spark apps in oozie and they work fine except for this use case that contains hiveContext.**

**Here is the workflow.xml:**

```
<workflow-app name="spark-scala" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="spark-5a6a"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-5a6a">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>local</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>MySpark</name>
              <class>ThirdApp</class>
            <jar>third-project_2.10-1.0.jar</jar>
            <file>/user/cloudera/oozie-spark/third-project_2.10-1.0.jar#third-project_2.10-1.0.jar</file>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

**Here is the job.properties:**

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=True
send_email=False
dryrun=False
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
jobTracker=quickstart.cloudera:8032
security_enabled=False
```

Kindly be informed that I added spark superuser group from **Cloudera Manager > Category > Security > Superuser group** , to avoid Permission issues:

[Adding spark to superuser group (Cloudera Manager View)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0prsv.png)

[hive-site.xml view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRH4R.png)

**stdout logs:**

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exception invoking main(), PermGen space

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild  - Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

WARN  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Unexpected error reading responses on connection Thread[IPC Client (1722336150) connection to /127.0.0.1:59738 from job_1547905343759_0002,5,main]

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Communication exception: java.io.IOException: The client is stopped

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler  - Thread Thread[main,5,main] threw an Error.
```

**stderr logs:**

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exception invoking main(), PermGen space
Halting due to Out Of Memory Error...

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

**syslog:**

```
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
NFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1547905343759_0002, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@3a06520)
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: RM_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 127.0.0.1:8032, Ident: (RM_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=cloudera, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=oozie, issueDate=1547907649379, maxDate=1548512449379, sequenceNumber=6, masterKeyId=2)
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /yarn/nm/usercache/cloudera/appcache/application_1547905343759_0002
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.OozieLauncherInputFormat$EmptySplit@1ab7aa29
NFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 0
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
NFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032
```

And I also looked for logs in **Cloudera Manager > Logs > ERROR**:

```
Exception in doCheckpoint
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RetriableException): NameNode still not started
...(more)

Error starting JobHistoryServer
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/history/done]
...
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RetriableException): NameNode still not started
...(more)

SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[-] JOB[0000001-190120120522295-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-190120120522295-oozie-oozi-W@spark-5a6a] XException, 
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0800: Action it is not running its in [KILLED] state, action [0000001-190120120522295-oozie-oozi-W@spark-5a6a]
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.CompletedActionXCommand.eagerVerifyPrecondition(CompletedActionXCommand.java:92)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

getting attribute DatanodeNetworkCounts of Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=DataNodeInfo threw an exception
javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrow(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:839)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrowMaybeMBeanException(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:852)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:651)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.jmx.JMXJsonServlet.writeAttribute(JMXJsonServlet.java:342)
...More
```

**Here is an (approximate) full view of the logs:**

[/var/log/spark/...log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFqTS.png)

[/var/log/hadoop-hdfs/...log.out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZTUe.png)

I've tried to fix these problems by:

**Increasing memory for map/reduce in mapred-site.xml:**

```
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>2128</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>2128</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>2128</value>
  </property>
```

[Global View of mapred-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fsD6.png)

**I tried also to increase Java Heap:**
[View of Java Heap in Cloudera Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX0YA.png)

I tried also to set Gateway Default Group:
[View of Client Java Configuration Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz9dw.png)

And I've tried to add Options list in the workflow that says: **--driver-memory 5G**

But it's always giving the same error.
Could you please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the memory issue - but I've seen the "permission denied" issue
For some reasons the folder '/user/spark/applicationHistory/local-1547821006998' is owned by user 'cloudera' and not spark, so spark cannot write to it.
To resolve it, login to the VM and add the group supergroup to the user spark:
"usermod -G supergroup saprk"
cheers, Doron

Comment: Hi Doron, It's fine know concerning permission issues after adding spark user. But I've got some other errors. Can you please check the updates I made. Thanks, EL MEHDI